# Single API for Web and Mobile

Tags: mobile, api-design

If I've Single API for Web and Mobile then how can accomplish following things.

1. In web I need to display 10 fields but in mobile may be 3 fields only?
2. Basically we will have tight coupling on DB proc side as well if there is a change(Requirement) for WEB, then it could be hit Mobile as well?
3. Testing -> May be lot of testing for all platforms?

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is that you add a extra field into your API maybe call it `channel`, then use that `channel` field to indicate `web` or `mobile` channel.

Comment: So you mean to say internally I should route my request based on caller(Web,Mobile) ? if yes that means I will maintain different DB Procs & methods